# What does this occult symbol signify?

Tags: magic, spawn

I remember seeing this symbol in other works, but I cannot for the life of me remember where I originally saw it or anywhere I've ever seen it specifically....

[image: occult symbol]

The circle, with a dot in the center, with a spike (not an arrow) pointed down from the end of the bottom of the circle.

This particular image is from the Spawn Fan Film [RECALL](http://therecall-movie.com/) (6:26)

Comment: I searched this [whole website](http://www.symbols.com) and came up with nothing..

Comment: There's a few in that shape (including that the line doesn't have an arrow or bar), but they don't point in that direction.  It's always towards the upper right or bottom left.  Are you sure the image isn't rotated, or if from TV that they weren't showing it at an angle?

Comment: So seeing the source now... this is on the character's forehead?  Are you sure you're not just mixing up the occult with an elaborate [bindi](http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/236x/79/5c/58/795c58c5b27154d17c686be857ff2ca0.jpg)?

Comment: I remember where I've seen it before, sort of.... I've seen the image in such a way that it surrounds the eyes. Usually in gothic makeup. Same concept, spike facing down, with a circle drawn around each eye and a spike going towards the cheek

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### It is a sun symbol. It is a recurring symbol that shows up in the video. Once, on her hand, once on a necklace both she and the boy are wearing.

[image: Solar Symbol] — Solar Symbol

[image]

It shows up twice in the video, once as a necklace, again as a symbol on the witch's hand and finally as the sun symbol on her forehead.

[image]

[image]

- There is no line at the bottom, it is an artifact of the design process. Check out the complete face picture, there are lines below her eyes as well similar to the line at the Solar symbol on her face. The lines are part of a design process, not a part of the logo.

Comment: I see where your going with this, but I have a hard time seeing the symbols as the same. Which is to say, you bear a strong point, but I'm not quite convinced? Especially since I've since watched that few seconds of the video several times to verify, and I'm certain that spike is deliberate, and not an 'artifact of the design process' as you say it is.

Comment: @Thaddeus:
The director emailed me back and indeed, it is a circumpunct. Yours is the considerably more detailed answer.

Comment: @SeanDuggan & Friends. I appreciate all your help, thanks much!

Answer (score 7):

The circle with a dot in it is the Circumpunct, also known as the Solar Symbol. It's not generally depicted with the line at the bottom, which I can see in the film is indeed a straight line with no arrow or cross. There is a circle without a dot with a line drawn off of it to represent a Conjunction of planets. Perhaps the symbol is supposed to indicate a Conjunction with the Sun? You can see examples of the symbols [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_symbols).

[image: Solar Symbol] — Solar Symbol

[image: Conjunction] — Conjunction

Truthfully, I suspect that the filmmaker made up their own symbol. The director, Michael Paris, has an email listed on his webpage. I sent a message asking if he could elucidate and he responded:

> Hi Sean,
>   You are right, on the Witch's forhead, this is a circumpunct, a logogram
>   for the sun in Egyptian hieroglyphs.
>   The stroke under the circle is just merged with the circumpunct for design
>   purpose.
>   Thank you for your interrest
>   Regards
>
> Michael Paris

So I was right that it's a Solar Symbol, but reaching by adding the Conjunction, although he sent a follow-up message:

> But your "cunjunction" hypothesis is pretty interesting. 
>   Thanks for bringing that up

Comment: Yeah, Conjunction was one of the ones I found.  "Day" is the same symbol but with a longer stem, then "Night" is the same as "Day" but going in the opposite direction.  I think there was one other with that shape, but I no longer have my tabs open...